# I cannot change Page Wrapper

Tags: magento2, page

I will start with a strange problem that I cannot find its solution for a week.

In my template, there are a lot of kind of headers. In the most of them there is a problem.

They have a line in top in which there is the text "Free Shipping On Orders Over $59".

[image]

Is there anyone that can help me changing this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what is the issue exactly do you want to change the shipping text or add some css / div around whole page wrapper ?

Comment: I cannot do neither of the them.

Comment: You must find the text without price in your files project and in database project and you to find where is.

Comment: Can you explain further your opinion?